# Adding things to basic bash commands without creating infinite loops

Tags: ls, bash, cd

I would like to make a script to modify some basic command-line commands like `ls` or `cd` which would end up calling the normal `ls` or `cd` commands but without creating infinite loops. How could I do that?

So, what I was thinking of doing is something like creating a cd2.sh file like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Oh! Your are changing directories'
cd "$@"
```

and then put an alias in `.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile` for mac):

```
alias cd = 'cd2.sh'
```

but this creates an infinite loop and my computer is not very happy about that. Is there an easy way to achieve my goal?

Comment: You need to quote a string like `cd` if you want to treat it like a string rather than as a command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `command` command, or its shortcut notation `\`. Since `cd` is a builtin, you could also use the `builtin` command. They ignore functions and aliases and instead look up an executable directly in the `$PATH` and/or the built-ins.

> ```
> $ alias ls='echo no ls for you!'
> $ ls
> no ls for you!
> $ command ls
> [directory listing]
> $ \ls
> [directory listing]
> ```

Comment: or alternatively `\ls`

Comment: @karakfa thanks, I didn't know about this shortcut, I've edited my answer to mention it.

Comment: or alternatively `builtin ls' - so many ways to skin a cat :-)

Comment: @SaintHax the more the merrier, I've added it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I can do it the following simple form for ls.

mode of use: ./cd2.sh -s ./folder

## !/bin/bash

ls $@

Answer (score 0):

check out these links to see if you are helpful

http://ubunlog.com/creando-comandos-personalizados-en-ubuntu/
http://www.archivoslog.es/2009/07/usar-alias-y-crear-comandos-personalizados-en-linux/